# How to pass a datetime variable into a SQL String on the correct format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio with SQL scripts.

My problem: I have 2 variables that return datetime i.e. 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000, I'm trying to add these variables into a SQL string, but when I do it format get lost and it gets converted to  this: Apr  1 2019 12:00AM. The date on that format does not work in my SQL script

I've tried multiple convert and cast codes but it does not work at all , below is what I'm getting on the `@InvoiceTrue` variable:

```
left join table1 payment on l.LedgerID = payment.LedgerID
left join table2 i on payment.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
where l.BusinessDate between 'Apr  1 2019 12:00AM' and 'Apr  7 2019 12:00AM' 
order by l.LedgerID
```

If you look above, the date time format is getting lost.

This is my SQL code:

```
Declare
    @innerBeginDate datetime = '2019-04-01'
,   @innerEndDate datetime = '2019-04-07'
,   @InvoiceTrue varchar(max)

Select @InvoiceTrue = N'
    left join table1 payment on l.LedgerID = payment.LedgerID
    left join table2 i on payment.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
    where l.BusinessDate between ''' +  CAST(@innerBeginDate as varchar) + ''' and ''' + CAST(@innerEndDate as varchar) + ''' order by l.LedgerID'''

select @InvoiceTrue
```

I need to keep the same datetime format after passing the parameter into the string to be always like 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using dynamic SQL? Its not clear from your questions what you're trying to do. Anyway assuming you need to format a datetime as a string just check the reference docs for which format you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: any reason that you need to use `dynamic query` ?

Comment: I'm using dynamic query to reduce the sql line code because later I'm doing an if condition where I'm adding the result of the  @InvoiceTrue variable to another sql string

Comment: Bad habits to unlearn - declaring strings without a length (e.g., "cast (... as varchar)".

Comment: Bad habits to unlearn - casting date (and related datatypes) to varchar without a style will produce inconsistent output since it depends on runtime settings. So always specify a style that can be interpreted correctly depending on your goal. Read Tibor's exhaustive discussion of [datetime datatype](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) here - yes READ it - no tl/dr.

Comment: Thank you Smor , I'll take that in consideration from now on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2019-04-01'
select convert(varchar, @date, 13);  

Output is: 01 Apr 2019 00:00:00:000
```

If you wish to see different convert formats in operation, then you can use the following snippet:

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 0
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2019-04-01'

CREATE TABLE #dateFormats (dateFormatOption int, dateOutput varchar(40))

WHILE (@counter <= 150 )
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO #dateFormats
      SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @counter), CONVERT(varchar,@date, @counter) 
      SET @counter = @counter + 1
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH;
      SET @counter = @counter + 1
      IF @counter >= 150
      BEGIN
         BREAK
      END
   END CATCH
END

SELECT * FROM #dateFormats;
```

Reference: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: Thank you so much , I've replaced the cast with convert plus the counter and is returning the data I need. I'm just getting an error : Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.